# Remember Me functionality using CheckBox ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I am trying to implement remember user and password when user click on remember me checkbox.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    UserName:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
    Password:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" TextMode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
    Remember me:
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRememberMe" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="Login_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Saving the UserName and Password in Cookie

```
   if (chkRememberMe.Checked)
    {
        Response.Cookies["UserName"].Value = username;
        Response.Cookies["Password"].Value = password;
        Response.Cookies["UserName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
        Response.Cookies["Password"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Cookies["UserName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        Response.Cookies["Password"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
 
    }
```

Populating the UserName and Password from Cookie and setting it in TextBoxes

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request.Cookies["UserName"] != null && Request.Cookies["Password"] != null)
        {
            txtUserName.Text = Request.Cookies["UserName"].Value;
            txtPassword.Attributes["value"] = Request.Cookies["Password"].Value;
        }
    }
}
```

I know that using above method is not secure as we are storing username and password as plain text in cookie.
Is there any method where I can implement it using token based instead of storing username and password?

I have attempted to generate the token and retrieve the username using the provided code, but I encountered an issue. The problem lies in the fact that the generated token is not being stored in the database, which prevents the retrieval of the associated username. Is there any way we can retrieve username? Any help or suggestion would be really appreciated.

here is my updated code:

```
// Generate a secure token
   string token = GenerateSecureToken();
   if (chkRememberMe.Checked)
    {
         HttpCookie userCookie = new HttpCookie("user");
         userCookie["token"] = token;
         userCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15);
         Response.Cookies.Add(userCookie);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Cookies["UserName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        Response.Cookies["Password"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
 
    }

private string GenerateSecureToken()
{
    byte[] tokenData = new byte[32]; 
    using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        rng.GetBytes(tokenData);
    }

    string token = BitConverter.ToString(tokenData).Replace("-", "").ToLower();

    return token;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      HttpCookie userCookie = Request.Cookies["user"];
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (userCookie != null)
            {
             string token = userCookie["token"];
             string username = GetUsernameFromToken(token);
             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
             {
              txtusername.Text = username;
              chkRememberMe.Checked = true;
             }
           }
    }
```

I am not sure how i can get the username from token.

```
private string GetUsernameFromToken(string token)
{
//here get the username 
}
```